# js works inside the page but not in code behind

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have this function put in a MasterPage, which shows up an mp3 player:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var stageW = 500;
        var stageH = 216;
        var cacheBuster = Date.parse(new Date());

        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};

        params.bgcolor = '#F6F6F6';
        params.allowfullscreen = 'true';


        flashvars.stageW = stageW;
        flashvars.stageH = stageH;

        flashvars.pathToFiles = '';

        flashvars.settingsPath = '../mp3player/mp3player_settings.xml';
        flashvars.xmlPath = '<%# getRestXmlPlayerUrl() %>';

        flashvars.keepSelected = 't';
        flashvars.selectedWindow = '4';
        flashvars.slideshow = 't';

        flashvars.imageWidth = '130';
        flashvars.imageHeight = '130';

        swfobject.embedSWF('swf/preview.swf?t=' + cacheBuster, 'myContent', stageW, stageH, '9.0.124', 'swf/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params);
    }); 
    </script>
```

All works great.
But, because i have some ajax on the page with update panel, the flash in not rendered when ajax requests occurs so i need to register this function and i've tried something like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    String csnameForPlayer = "applyStyleToMp3Player";
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, csnameForPlayer))
        {
            StringBuilder cstextForPlayer = new StringBuilder();
            cstextForPlayer.Append(" $(document).ready(function() { "
    + " var stageW = 500;"
    + " var stageH = 216;"
    + " var cacheBuster = Date.parse(new Date());"

    + " var flashvars = {};"
    + " var params = {};"

    + " params.bgcolor = '#F6F6F6';"
    + " params.allowfullscreen = 'true';"


    + " flashvars.stageW = stageW;"
    + " flashvars.stageH = stageH;"

    + " flashvars.pathToFiles = '';"

    + " flashvars.settingsPath = '../mp3player/mp3player_settings.xml';"
    + " flashvars.xmlPath = '<%# getRestXmlPlayerUrl() %>';"

    + " flashvars.keepSelected = 't';"
    + " flashvars.selectedWindow = '4';"
    + " flashvars.slideshow = 't';"

    + " flashvars.imageWidth = '130';"
    + " flashvars.imageHeight = '130';"

   + " swfobject.embedSWF('swf/preview.swf?t=' + cacheBuster, 'myContent', stageW, stageH, '9.0.124', 'swf/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params);"
   + "});   ");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), csnameForPlayer, cstextForPlayer.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Well, this does not work. The flash player does not appear any more, so, i assume that is something wrong in the cstextForPlayer.

I've spent over one hour to figure it out but i've failed.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give us the html-output!

Answer (score 3):

`<%# getRestXmlPlayerUrl() %>` is the part that causes problems. When used in `RegisterStartupScript` it won't return any value but it will be hardcoded. Now instead of going through all the pain of mixing C# and javascript I would recommend you externalizing this script into a function, it's always better to use the right tools for the right thing:

```
function embedPlayer(xmlPath) {
    var stageW = 500;
    var stageH = 216;
    var cacheBuster = Date.parse(new Date());

    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};

    params.bgcolor = '#F6F6F6';
    params.allowfullscreen = 'true';


    flashvars.stageW = stageW;
    flashvars.stageH = stageH;

    flashvars.pathToFiles = '';

    flashvars.settingsPath = '../mp3player/mp3player_settings.xml';
    flashvars.xmlPath = xmlPath;

    flashvars.keepSelected = 't';
    flashvars.selectedWindow = '4';
    flashvars.slideshow = 't';

    flashvars.imageWidth = '130';
    flashvars.imageHeight = '130';

    swfobject.embedSWF('swf/preview.swf?t=' + cacheBuster, 'myContent', stageW, stageH, '9.0.124', 'swf/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params);
}
```

This would simplify your server side code to simply calling the previous function and passing it the xml path as argument:

```
string csnameForPlayer = "applyStyleToMp3Player";
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), csnameForPlayer))
{
    var script = string.Format("embedPlayer('{0}');", this.getRestXmlPlayerUrl());
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.Page, 
        this.Page.GetType(), 
        csnameForPlayer, 
        script, 
        true
    );
}
```

Comment: It is not about repeating code, in your case you didn't repeat any code, it's about having proper code. For example when you keep your javascript code into js files your web application will automatically benefit from things like caching, gzip compression etc. If you put this into your C# code, your ajax requests will be heftier and not optimized.

Answer (score 2):

I frankly don't know a lot about code-behind, but this line:

```
+ " flashvars.xmlPath = '<%# getRestXmlPlayerUrl() %>';"
```

...looks likely to be a problem. Shouldn't that be:

```
+ " flashvars.xmlPath = '" + getRestXmlPlayerUrl() + "';"
```

...or something?